# Numpy array float precision is not deterministic

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, floating-point, precision

So when running the below snipet

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([-0.20000008], dtype=np.float32)
np.floor((X + 1) / 0.04)
```

```
array([20.], dtype=float32)
```

The output is obviously wrong as the result should be below 20 and should floor to 19

I get that this is precision errors but running all below samples produce correct results although it should have similar precision

```
X = np.array([-0.20000008], dtype=np.float32).item()
np.floor((X + 1) / 0.04) # 19.0
```

```
X = np.float32(-0.20000008)
np.floor((X + 1) / 0.04) # 19.0
```

```
X = np.array([-0.20000008], dtype=np.float32)
np.floor(X / 0.04 + 1 / 0.04) # array([19.], dtype=float32)
np.floor(np.multiply((X + 1), 1/0.04)) # array([19.], dtype=float32)
```

If I cast it as float64 it works too but it is very expensive cast for my application. Any solutions while sticking to float32?

Comment: What about using np.array([np.floor((x + 1) / 0.04) for x in X]) based on your observations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try to understand the first two of the three examples on the bottom first:

In the first example

```
np.array([-0.20000008], dtype=np.float32).item()
```

will produce a native python `float()` which is a 64 bit, so no surprizes here.

In the second example you have create a numpy 32-bit *scalar* (`shape==(), type==np.float32`) which will get treated more or less like other scalars: So as soon as you add an `int` (1), the result will be a 64 bit number.

The interesting case now is actually your initial piece of code and the third example: In both cases you now have an *array* (`shape==(1,), type=np.ndarray`). In the case of operations with an array and a scalar, the type of the array will be preserved. So now we actually just have the issue that the *distributive* law does not hold for floating point numbers. Here you're doing computations that rely on the least significant bits of floating point numbers.

Comment: Interesting. But how to explain that `((X + np.float32(1)) / 0.04).dtype` is float32 and `((X[0] + np.float32(1)) / 0.04).dtype` is float64?

Comment: In the first example `X` is an `np.ndarray` while in the second one `X[0]` will be a `np.float32` *scalar*, so it's again a similar situation to what I mentioned in the answer. Note that `X[0]` is not the same as `X.item()` here, the former still gets you a numpy object, while the latter will be a native python `float`!

Comment: So to answer your question, in the first case we have an array and the type of the array is preserved through the operation with scalars, in the second case we hava scalars, among which is a 64 bit `float` (0.04), the result will be a 64 bit number.

Comment: What about ``np.floor(np.multiply((X + 1), 1/0.04))`` which produces 19.0 as well

Comment: @ma7555 I'd suggest dividing it up into all the intermediate results, inspecting the types and then thinking about where exactly you find a difference to what you expect!

Comment: @flawr I know the type of `X` and `X[0]` are different. The main point of my question was why the behaviour is chosen to be different with scalars? I expect the same behaviour with array: a cast to float64. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Yes, check out e.g. the page on [np.result_type](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html)! Of course I can't answer *why* it was chosen that way, but to me it seems to be the most practical and widespread solution, but that clearly is subjective.